# Model Averaging errors using lme4 in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, model-averaging

I am running a glmer model on a response variable with binomial distribution and random term. My data has 3 explanatory categorical variables and I have successfully run dredge() on them and their interactions to get AICc values.

I want model averaging to provide output with coefficients and an index of relative importance of fixed effects from those models; within a delta constraint that I specify.I can get this using the code below for alternative datasets but not for this dataset.
This is what I have input.

```
ae <- read.csv(file=file.choose())
options(na.action="na.fail")
global.model<-glmer(
     cbind(numerator,total-numerator)~d+s+t+d:s:t+d:s+d:t+s:t+(1|random), 
     data=ae, family=binomial)   
options(max.print=1000000)
dredge(global.model,beta=c("none"),evaluate=TRUE,rank="AICc") 
ae.model <- glmer(
     cbind(numerator,total-numerator)~d+s+t+d:s:t+d:s+d:t+s:t+(1|random),
    data=ae,family=binomial)
models <- dredge(ae.model)  
summary(model.avg(get.models(models,subset=delta<5)))
```

model.avg() produces this error message:

> Error in model.avg.default(get.models(models, subset = delta < 5)) :
>   models are not unique. Duplicates: '2 = 3 = 4' and '10 = 11'

This doesn't make sense, DREDGE does not (cannot) produce duplicate models – each model is a unique iteration within the full model, yet the error message indicates that MODEL AVERAGE identified ‘duplicate’ models from within DREDGE output. R fails to run MODEL AVERAGE under these circumstances - producing no further output.

**Has anyone else experienced similar problem (with 'not unique', duplicate models) via MODEL AVERAGE?**

Is there a workaround for the error that prevents me running MODEL AVERAGE due to perceived ‘duplicate’ models in DREDGE?
Summary of data below:

```
summary(ae)
  p                   t           day             hour            scan             random    behaviour  
 ae:182   blood        :42   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   : 0   ae_blood_1_1:  7   alert:182  
          egg          :35   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:10   ae_blood_1_2:  7              
          repellentfree:63   Median :2.000   Median :2.000   Median :30   ae_blood_1_3:  7              
          wolf         :42   Mean   :1.654   Mean   :1.962   Mean   :30   ae_blood_2_1:  7              
                             3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:50   ae_blood_2_2:  7              
                             Max.   :3.000   Max.   :3.000   Max.   :60   ae_blood_2_3:  7              
                                                                          (Other)     :140              
   numerator           total      proportion        percentage      d                        s     
 Min.   : 0.0000   Min.   :17   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   : 0.000   E :14   1 - very light wind:21  
 1st Qu.: 0.0000   1st Qu.:17   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.: 0.000   SE:84   2 - light wind     :70  
 Median : 0.0000   Median :17   Median :0.00000   Median : 0.000   SW:35   3 - moderate wind  :77  
 Mean   : 0.5824   Mean   :17   Mean   :0.03426   Mean   : 3.426   W :49   4 - heavy wind     :14  
 3rd Qu.: 0.0000   3rd Qu.:17   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.: 0.000                                   
 Max.   :16.0000   Max.   :17   Max.   :0.94118   Max.   :94.118
```